# spring MVC, Jboss 7

Tags: spring-mvc, jboss7.x

I am trying to build a sample spring MVC app using Maven and getting deployed in JBoss 7 application server.

While trying to build using maven, it builds fine without error. However while trying to deploy using JBoss 7, I am getting this following error.

Kindly help to give ideas what might be the cause of this error.

```
13:48:36,408 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."firstSpring-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."firstSpring-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "firstSpring-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war"
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error getting reflective information for class org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.EvalTag with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.firstSpring-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war:main" from Service Module Loader
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/expression/PropertyAccessor
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.expression.PropertyAccessor from [Module "deployment.firstSpring-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
```

Comment: It seems to be a missing jar on your classpath. Check if you have teh spring expressions jar correctly on your war lib's folder.

Comment: I am actually using maven for this. I added the spring expression as a maven dependency and still getting the same error. My application builds fine but while launching getting this runtime exception

Comment: did you have these another dependencies described here: http://mavenhub.com/c/org/springframework/web/servlet/tags/evaltag/dependency ?

Comment: Please do `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose=true`. Check for version conflicts or missing `spring-expression` (not a transitive dependency). If you won't be able to find the cause yourself, post the output here.

Comment: @Pavel Horal: i issued the maven command and it builds successfully. It downloaded all the required jar without any version conflicts or missing expression.

Comment: The command is not about finishing successfully. You actually need to study the output as it prints dependency versions and how transitive dependencies are being handled. Can you include the full dependency tree within your question?